# Display shipping method on cart page by default

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I'm building a custom shipping method for a specific location. However, I would still like to show the shipping method as a default option regardless of it is a default, knowing or not knowing the customer location or having a base calculation rate.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can only do that for the specific location, as anyway, your custom shipping method will not show up on others locations. Note that WooCommerce detects the guest location, if IP geolocation is enabled.